# How can I create a pixel labelled image for Semantic Segmentation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, matlab

I am following the [Semantic Segmentation Examples](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/semantic-segmentation-examples.html#mw_44be2a2e-ec6b-4a03-9470-ea945f74515e) tutorial by MathWorks.

I understand that I can load pixel labeled images

```
pxDir = fullfile(dataDir,'buildingPixelLabels');
```

Define the class names.

```
classNames = ["sky" "grass" "building" "sidewalk"];
```

Define the label ID for each class name.

```
pixelLabelID = [1 2 3 4];
```

and create a pixelLabelDatastore.

```
pxds = pixelLabelDatastore(pxDir,classNames,pixelLabelID);
```

But, how do I **create a custom pixel labelled image** where every pixel value represents the categorical label of that pixel?

I would then proceed by writing:

```
pxDir = fullfile(dataDir,'myCustomPixelLabels');
```

If I understood correctly, `imageDatastore` holds the actual image and not the pixel labels for that image.

---

**EDIT:**

On my system `pxDir` points to `'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\toolbox\vision\visiondata\buildingPixelLabels'`. Since I am on Matlab2017a so this example is not included by default, and I cannot compare or view the file to get a better understanding of what I need to do to reproduce this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/get-started-with-the-image-labeler.html).

Go to the **APPS** tab, and search for `Image Labeler`, or `Training Image Labeler`

Click on `Add Images` to add your training images.

Click on `Add ROI Labels` to add class names for the regions of interest.

Proceed to select the regions of interest manually from the uploaded images.